# Profiling with an external counter or best alternative

Tags: opencv, profiling, external, counter

I'am non-programmer, trying to assess the time spent in (opencv-)functions. We have an AD-converter which comes with a counter that is able to count external signals (e.g. from a function generator) with a frequency of 1 MHz = 1 µs resolution. The actual counter status can be queried with a function cbIn32(..., unsigned long *pointertovalue).

So my idea was to query the counter status before and after calling the function of interest and to calculate then the difference. However, doubts came up when I calcultated the difference without a function call in between, which revealed rel. high fluctuations (values between 80 and 400 µs or so). I wondered, if calculating the average time for calling cbIn32() (approx. 180 µs) and substract this from the putative time spent in the function of interest is a valid solution.

So my first two questions:

1. Is that approach generally feasible or useless?
2. Where do the fluctuations come from?

Alternatively, we tried using getTickCount(), which seemed to deliver reasonable values. But checking forums revealed that it has a low resolution of about 10 ms, which would be insatisfactory (100 µs resolution would be appreciated). However, the values we got were in the sub-ms range.
This brings me to the next questions:

1. How can the time assessed for a function with getTickCount() be in the microseconds range, when the resolution is around 10 ms?
2. Should I trust the obtained values or not?

I also tried it with gprof, but it gave me "no time accumulated", although I am sure that the time spent in a function containing opencv-related calls is at least a few milliseconds. I even tried rebuilding opencv with ENABLE_PROFILING=ON, but same result. I read somewhere that you need to build static opencv libraries to enable profiling, but I am not sure if this would improve the situation. So the question here is:

1. What do I have to do so that gprof also "sees" opencv functions?

Next alternative would be the QueryPerformanceCounter() function of the WINAPI. I don't how to use it, but I would fight my way through, if you recommend it. Question to that approach:

1. Will it be problematic because of multiple cores?
2. If yes, is there an "easy" way to handle that problem?

I also tried it with verysleepy, but it exits somehow to early (worked fine with other .exe).

Newbie-friendly answers would be very, very appreciated. My goal is to find the easiest approach with highest precision. I'm working on Win7 64bit, Eclipse with MinGW.

Thx for your help...

Comment: The best way to get precision timing measurements of something fast is to loop whatever it is 10^n times, time it end-to-end, and divide by 10^n.

Comment: Thx. The code is connected to live imaging of samples with subsequent analysis (thats the opencv part). So this would be difficult to implement.